# Terminal sending error 11

Tags: software-installation

When trying to install any package in a terminal, I get the following error

```
Not possible to block /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Temporaly not available resource )
```

This started happening after trying to install Microsoft font libraby. It stopped at:

```
"ttf-mscorefonts-installer" configuration window
```

Answer (score 1):

This has already been answered - [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/fixing-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock/15469#15469). Just run:

```
sudo fuser -cuk /var/lib/dpkg/lock; sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey the problem is simple
probably your previous installation of software was interrupted.Hence the lock file is still locked by the previous installation.Do this thing it may help try again to install the software ,if still the error comes then reboot the system and try the software center to install a software.